# RestTemplate HttpServerErrorException from POST

Tags: resttemplate

I am getting below error while making a POST call to external service. I am not setting any cookie in Headers while making request. Please help.

org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: [{"fault":{"faultstring":"Execution of JavaScriptQueryParams failed with error: Exception thrown from JavaScript : Error: Request with input param- Cookie & request verb- POST rejected as unsafe.Please check (JavaScriptQueryParams_js#126)","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.javascript.ScriptExecutionFailed"}}}]